# docker -v command doesn't mount files in a directory in Linux

Tags: linux, docker, docker-volume

Simple docker mount doesn't mount files from the host to the container. See the following command. I have some files under `node` directory. But when mounted in a volume the files are not showing up in the container.

```
$
$ls node
index.js  node_modules
$
$docker run -ti --rm -v $(pwd)/node:/node lyft/envoy:latest /bin/bash
root@94cde9bd4114:/# cd node
root@94cde9bd4114:/node# ls
root@94cde9bd4114:/node# ls -a
.  ..
```

Comment: This works as expected for me.  What version of docker are you using?

Comment: Also, what shell are you running on the host?

Comment: It works fine for me too, what's the output of `ps aux | grep 'docker run -ti'` on your host?

Comment: Is `$(pwd)/node` on a mount which was added after the docker daemon was last started? Docker won't pick up new mounts without a restart. this is a long shot...

Comment: I just stumbled upon this issue. Restarting docker did the job for me.